# Преобразовать список списков в один список

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как преобразовать список списков в один список?

`[[123], [456], [123, 4, 5, 6]]` → `[123, 456, 123, 4, 5, 6]`

Comment: Список списков в один список по какому принципу? В какую строку? Приведите примеры входных и ожидаемых выходных данных.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов Посмотрите ответы. Я задал вопрос и сам на него ответил. По-моему Вы придираетесь.

Comment: @hedgehogues, вопросы нужно задавать так, чтобы вопрос был понятен не только вам, даже если вы сами на него отвечаете (это вообще не должно никак влиять на формулировку вопроса). stackoverflow не только для вас, но и для других участников.

Comment: @insolor Вы исказили то, что я спрашивал. Я не просил сделать однострочником. Зачем Вы устраиваете произвол? Мало того, ещё и написали несогласованное предложение.

Comment: @hedgehogues, я могу ошибиться, как и любой человек. Но если бы вопрос был сформулирован нормально, то и не требовались бы правки. Сформулируйте вопрос так, чтобы **из самого вопроса было понятно, что вы хотите получить**. Пока голосую за закрытие вопроса.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что текст вопроса должен содержать необходимое и достаточное количество информации для его решения. (Информация из ответов под данным вопросом - не считается)

Comment: @МихаилРебров, добавил пример в текст

Comment: @mymedia, да, спасибо. Просто хотелось бы чтобы ТС изначально оформлял свои вопросы надлежащим образом.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```py
l1 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
print(sum(l1, [])) # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

from itertools import chain
print(list(chain.from_iterable(l1))) # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

l2 = [['12', '34'], ['56', '78']]
print(list(map(''.join, l2))) # ['1234', '5678']
```

Варианты со сторонними библиотеками:

```py
from numpy import array
from pandas.core.common import flatten

l = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]

print(list(array(l).flat))
print(list(flatten(l)))
```

Comment: А если там лежит объект произвольной природы?

Comment: @hedgehogues иметь у объекта `__add__`/воспользоваться вторым вариантом/воспользоваться вашим вариантом

Comment: @hedgehogues но первый вариант будет работать, если в самих листах произвольный объект, ведь складываются листы, а не объекты

Comment: По поводу numpy -- да. Но не всегда хочется ставить либу.

Comment: И преобразовывать к array

Comment: `chain` - самый хрестоматийный способ. Он будет работать и со списками и с кортежами и с генераторами и с любыми объектами, поддерживающими механизм итерирования.

Comment: `sum` на списках тормозит. Попробуйте `sum([[0]] * 100000, [])`.

Answer (score 3):

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists):

```
from functools import reduce #python 3

>>> l = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6], [7], [8,9]]
>>> reduce(lambda x,y: x+y,l)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

```
>>> import operator
>>> l = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6], [7], [8,9]]
>>> reduce(operator.concat, l)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

```
>>> sum(l, [])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

```
import itertools
list2d = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7], [8,9]]
merged = list(itertools.chain(*list2d))
```

```
import itertools
list2d = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7], [8,9]]
merged = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(list2d))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def flatten(l):
    return [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
```

Comment: В чем смысл именно лямбды?

Comment: Я объявляю функцию в кор-либе и использую её.

Comment: Это конечно не столь важно, но каждый раз, когда вы даете имя лямбда-функции, вероятно, вы делаете что-то не так. Именованную функцию лучше определить как обычную, а еще лучше использовать уже готовое решение из стандартной библиотеки.

Comment: @mkkik разумно. Поправил

Answer (score 0):

```
vector = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18]]
a=[]
[[a.append(j) for j in i] for i in vector]
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @0xdb, видимо, нужный результат остаётся в переменной "a", но здесь он не печатается в консоль

Comment: За однобуквенные переменные бьют ногами.

Comment: Использовать списковое сокращение для вызова `.append` - то ещё извращение. Не делайте так. Либо обычные циклы с `.append`, либо списковое сокращение и используйте потом список, который получается именно через списковое сокращение.